# Use Chrome/FF beta version in selenoid

Tags: selenoid

I am using selenoid for automated e2e-testing and really like it. To ensure browser support on all versions, I am testing with different versions of Chrome/FF and now would need to also test with the beta versions of these browsers.
I found out [here](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_browser_image_information) that there is no built-in image for beta versions.

Is there another way to use beta versions anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We provide all automation scripts used to build browser images. See [this repository](http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-images/).
2. Regarding beta images - we have an [issue](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-images/issues/26) and hope to start building more versions including ESR and beta during next months.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much

Comment: Is there any estimation for when the beta images might be available?